# How do you convert a Jackson JsonNode to a List of some user defined object?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Whats the best way to extract an internal Json array to a Java list using Jackson (without converting the whole Json Structure).

Lets say I have the Json:

```
{
  "objects":"that",
  "I":"dont care about",
  "objectsiwant":[{object1, object2,...}]
}
```

And I want to end up with a list of some Pojo I have:

```
List<MyPojo> myPojoList;
```

It seems like I ought to be able to do something like:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(json);
JsonNode internalNode = rootNode.path("objectsiwant");
List<MyPojo> myPojoList = mapper.readValue(internalNode, new TypeReference<List<MyPojo>>(){});
```

Of course there is no such method signature, and it seems like there is probably something very similar to this in Jackson, but I have not been able to find it.

Comment: `mapper.readerFor(typeRef).readValue(jsonNode)`?

Comment: You should edit your post and add a tag for "jackson". Any reason you're choosing not to deserialize the entire JSON string into a usable object using Jackson annotations? As long as the object with a `List<MyPojo>` has its getters/setters/fields annotated, and the fields of `MyPojo` are annotated, then Jackson can do the hard work for you like building a `List<MyPojo>` for you. Are you familiar with `@JsonProperty`, `@JsonGetter` and `@JsonSetter` annotations?

Comment: The comment from JB-Niznet is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. I would upvote it if it were an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The comment above from JB Niznet is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again. Basically the line in question in the example here will look like:

```
List<MyPojo> myPojoList = mapper.readerFor(new TypeReference<List<MyPojo>>(){}).readValue(internalNode);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to read a part of (probably a big) JSON, you can use [json-path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) library that has a robust DSL for selecting one or multiple JSON nodes:

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
import net.minidev.json.JSONArray;

public class JsonPathTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("C://temp/test.json"))) {
            JSONArray objectsiwant = JsonPath.read(is, "$.objectsiwant");
            System.out.println(objectsiwant.get(0));  // HashMap
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```